# How can I import existing emails into a new Google Apps email account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, import, google-apps-email

I'm working on setting up a Google Apps account. As part of the switch, I'd like to import old emails for all users on the domain. I thought I could do this by using the mail fetcher functionality. However, when I try to do that, and enter the email address I want to fetch mail for, I get an error message:

[image]

The blacked out parts are the email address (which I'm also logged in as in the new Apps account).

Is there a way to import existing emails into this Apps account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The e-mail fetcher would only fetch new e-mails that are on the inbox of the POP account.

IMAP is the the [way to go](http://www.zoliblog.com/2007/10/24/simplified-guide-to-importing-all-your-archive-email-into-gmail/). Here's a quote from [another guide](http://lifehacker.com/#!332624/import-messages-into-gmail-via-imap):

> It was simple: I merely added Gmail as an IMAP account to my Apple Mail client, then just dragged folder-by-folder all the messages important to me onto my Gmail account. It took a while to transfer all the messages (be sure to open the Activity window in Mail to see your progress), but once it was done, all my old messages were safely stored in Gmail and had their original dates! Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This advice worked for me:

> Make up a bogus email address to get past the screen that
>   is giving you the error.
>
> Once you get past that screen enter in the proper credentials and
>   Gmail will bring in the emails.

src: http://www.e-webstyle.com/techinfo/google-apps/google-apps-add-mail-pop3-create-mail-account/